# SAS SQL join criteria

Tags: sql, sas

I am working on a project where I have inherited an SQL Join that uses join
criteria in a format I have not seen before. The basic format of the join
is this:

```
Proc Sql;
   create table mytest as
   select t1.var1,
          t1.var2,
          t1.var3
   from mysource1 t1
   left join mysource2 t2 on
(t1.var1 = t2.var1), myparam t3;
quit;
```

The bit I am confused about is why `myparam` is included as a join
condition within the `ON` statement of the `LEFT JOIN`. The contents of
'myparam' is derived from the SAS Parameter File we have defined on our
system and contains just one row, with two columns. One contains month
start date, the other month end date.

None of the columns in this parameter file are in the other two source
tables and none of the columns in the parameter file appear in the final
output (they aren't referenced in the `SELECT` statement so they won't do).

I'm guessing that including the 'myparam' dataset in this context is
somehow using the date values within in it to cut the data in `mysource1` and
`mysource2`, but could someone please provide confirmation that this is the
case and the exact mechanism at work please?

Thanks

Comment: I have had to post this from my phone as for some reason I cannot seem to post or amend questions using my work internet today, so could someone please edit the post so that the code section shows as code? Thanks.

Comment: Can't seem to edit it either! I stuck on IE7 though, which might explain it!

Comment: FYI - I recommend noting in the question when code derives from an automatic code generator, as it is often helpful to understand why strange things are done the way they are (such as the unusual join construction here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an unusual construction for a join in SAS, but it's basically a Cartesian product. The `myparam` table isn't part of the `LEFT JOIN` condition but a new table, starting a new join. Any table included using a comma and no join condition causes it to be joined with all rows from one table matching to all rows in the other. This can be dangerous when two large tables are used (as the amount of rows is multiplied) but in your case the `myparam` table has one row, so it's only `1 x n`.

However, saying all that, the query you have come across doesn't use any values from `myparam` (or `mysource2` for that matter), so I don't see why these tables are being joined on at all. I'm fairly certain the following query would be equivalent:

```
proc sql;
  select var1,var2,var3
  from mysource1;
quit;
```

I'm aware this answer might come across as incomplete, so please feel free to comment...

Comment: Thanks for responding. One field from t2 is used to create a new field in the output table within a 'case when' statement that I did not include for simplicity of the code for demonstration purposes. looking back though that has created some confusion as to why this merge is being done in the first place. Since I posted this question it turns out this code is a bit of a cut and shut from a DI job managled together with some base code and put into EG, so I cant be sure what is system generated and what isnt. Basically adding 't3.col1' and 't3.col2' creates the...

Comment: ...1 x N output you suggested, but this time with the columns for t3 included. these fields are not referenced anywhere within the job to cut the data and at present I dont know why this table is included within the merge. it maybe that someone went part way down this route, then decided against this method, but never removed the merge from the code.